# How can I run my application in the background python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to know that is it possible that i can run my application in background even if I click the cancel button. I design the application in `pyqt5` using `python` 
let's look at example in `android` if we want that this app will run in the background after i close the app for that we use different kind of methods one method is `Runnable`and the code example is below

```
Handler mainHandler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
@Override 
public void run() {....} // This is the work to do on the background
};
mainHandler.post(myRunnable);
```

I want to do like this If I close the application the app must run in the background and the icon goes to `show hidden icon` but in python.

Comment: Could you explain yourself better, maybe an example will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general when you want to run a python application on the background you use the module "daemon" that makes the process as a daemon or you can use the operator & at the end on unix. Have a look to the module daemon that may help you,